# How to disable all dates in Django's DateInput widget except for those stored in a list?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

first poster here in need of some help please. I'm building a web app with Django as a personal training project for bookings and I use a DateInput widget to display the dates for the user to select from. I somehow need to grey out(disable) everything, except for dates I have stored as objects in a list called available_dates. The list is asc ordered by date. I only managed to restrict the view to the first and last date available, but cannot figure out how to also disable the dates in between that are not available to book. Many thanks for any advice.

`print(available_dates)`

```
[<AvailableDate: 2023-05-25>, <AvailableDate: 2023-05-27>, <AvailableDate: 2023-05-28>]
```

And here is my DateInput class:

```py
class DateInputSpecific(forms.DateInput):
    input_type = 'date'
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.available_dates = kwargs.pop('available_dates', [])
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
    def get_context(self, name, value, attrs):
        attrs.setdefault('min', self.available_dates[0].date)
        attrs.setdefault('max', self.available_dates[len(self.available_dates)-1].date)
        context = super().get_context(name, value, attrs)
        return context
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of DateInput:

*Renders as: <input type="text" ...>*

So the functionality you seek is not built in. You could use validation in your form to reject invalid dates. Provided your template clearly displayed which dates are available, this should be minimally acceptable:

```
class MyForm( forms.Form):
    ...
    date = MyDate( ... ) # using above widget
    ...

    def clean_date(self):
        date = self.cleaned_data['date']
        if date not in self.available_dates:
            formatted_date = date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            raise ValidationError(
                f"Date {formatted_date} is not available"
            )
        return date
```

Beyond this, you are looking either at client-side coding (JS) to reject a non-avalable date as soon as it is entered into that field, or a change of approach. I would probably use a `forms.ChoiceField` with the choices defined dynamically:

```
choices = [ (date, date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') )
     for date in available_dates ]
```

Comment: I see. Thank you very much. At least now I know that I was chasing a dead end and can focus on alternatives. I haven't touched JS just yet. Appreciate your explanation.